# How to request keyboard input when a user presses a UIButton?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

In Swift Playgrounds for iPad, how do you request keyboard input when a user presses a UIButton, then pass the input to a variable or container?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to use a UITextField. Just by placing the text field on your storyboard, the user can click it and enter what they want. You can then pass what they entered into a variable by entering `var textEntered = textField.text`. If you really wanted to, you could also focus the textField when a button is tapped by putting `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` in the button’s action. If you don’t want the text field to be shown, you can put `textField.isHidden = true` in viewDidLoad. Hope this helps!

Comment: Just to clarify, this is a playground, so First Responder and viewDidLoad don't apply.